# Cancel an element that's not a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was going through the proof of "every PID is a UFD" in Serge Lang's Algebra-book and something confused me. When it comes to proving the uniqueness of the factorization, he writes:

"Suppose $a$ has two factorizations $a = p_1 \cdots p_r = q_1 \cdots q_s$ into irreducible elements. Since $p_1$ divides the product farthest to the right, $p_1$ divides one of the factors, which we may assume to be $q_1$ (...). Then there exists a unit $u_1$ such that $q_1 = u p_1$. We can now cancel $p_1$ from both factorizations (...)"

It's the very last sentence that confuses me. Why are we allowed to cancel $p_1$? We can't "divide" by $p_1$ since we do not know whether it has an inverse or not. Or is it really necessary that $x \mapsto p \cdot x$ is injective for arbitrary $p$'s in a ring?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Throughout,  we are working in an integral domain.

Comment: The context of UFDs and PIDs is that of commutative domains, these are commutative rings where $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$; equivalently where $ac=bc$ and $c\neq 0$ implies $a=b$.

Comment: Ah right! I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integral domains (ID) are the closest rings to fields. An element $x \ne 0$ does not necessarily have an inverse, yet if $xy = xz$ form some $y$ and $z$, then $x(y-z)=0$ and since an integral domain has no divisors of $0$ (and $x \ne 0$ by assumption) the only possibility is $y-z=0$, i.e. $y=z$ (as if multiplying by the non-existent $x^{-1}$ on the left).

There is an equivalent yet alternative view on this: the [total ring of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions) of an ID $R$ happens to be a field $F$ (the [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions)) in which $R$ embeds naturally: $r \mapsto \frac r 1$. Embed $xy=xz$ into $F$; here $x = \frac x 1$ will have an inverse by which you may multiply on the left, obtaining $\frac y 1 = \frac z 1$. Since $\frac y 1$ and $\frac z 1$ live in the image of the embedding (which is isomorphic to $R$), you may take these back into $R$ obtaining $y=z$.

Therefore, you may want to keep this in mind: integral domains (which are commutative by definition) are the closest thing to commutative fields.